# node.js + request => node.js + bluebird + request

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to understand how to write code with promises.
Check my code plz. This is right?

Node.js + request:

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonpData = body;
        var json;
        try {
            json = JSON.parse(jsonpData);
        } catch (e) {
            var startPos = jsonpData.indexOf('({');
            var endPos = jsonpData.indexOf('})');
            var jsonString = jsonpData.substring(startPos+1, endPos+1);
            json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        }
        callback(null, json);
    } else {
        callback(error);
    }
});
```

Node.js + bluebird + request:

```
request.getAsync(url)
   .spread(function(response, body) {return body;})
   .then(JSON.parse)
   .then(function(json){console.log(json)})
   .catch(function(e){console.error(e)});
```

How to check response status? I should use if from first example or something more interesting?

Comment: Where did `jsonString` come from?

Comment: @thefourtheye sry, forget part for catch(e) {...}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply check if the `response.statusCode` is not 200 in the `spread` handler and throw an `Error` from that, so that the `catch` handler will take care of it. You can implement it like this

```
var request = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('request'), {multiArgs: true});

request.getAsync(url).spread(function (response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode != 200)
        throw new Error('Unsuccessful attempt. Code: ' + response.statusCode);
    return JSON.parse(body);
}).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

And if you notice, we return the parsed JSON from the `spread` handler, because `JSON.parse` is not an async function, so we don't have to do it in a separate `then` handler.

Answer (score 0):

One way to check the status code:

```
.spread(function(response, body) {
  if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
    throw new Error('Unexpected status code');
  }
  return body;
})
```